# Extract text to the left of the '-'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the data to the left of the -  I tried the code below

```
LocationName
CCC-CC36-A
5N-N577-A
5N-N577-A
5N-N577-A
2T-225-A
PE-020-A

select 
LEFT(LocationName, LEN(LocationName) - CHARINDEX('-',LocationName)-1),
EncounterNumber
from #TubeRateQty
```

Comment: Maybe select 
LEFT(LocationName, CHARINDEX('-',LocationName)-1),
EncounterNumber
from #TubeRateQty

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 124
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: It probably should be select LEFT(LocationName, CHARINDEX('-',LocationName)), EncounterNumber from #TubeRateQt.  but I can't get sqlfiddle to work at the moment to test anything.  Are you sure all of your rows have a '-' in them?

Comment: Actually it does need the -1.  Look at this query in SEDE: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/502200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(LocationName, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-',LocationName),0), LEN(LocationName)+1)-1)
 ,EncounterNumber
from #TubeRateQty
```

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 124
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @user3666224 try now, it was erroring out if there was no `-` is the string, I have added some more checks to handle that situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @xml xml

SELECT @xml =(
    SELECT CAST('<i><a>' + REPLACE(LocationName,'-','</a><a>') + '</a></i>' as xml)
    FROM YourTable
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

SELECT  t.v.value('a[1]','nvarchar(100)'),
        t.v.value('a[2]','nvarchar(100)'),
        t.v.value('a[3]','nvarchar(100)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/i') as t(v)
```

Output:

```
CCC        CC36       A
5N         N577       A
5N         N577       A
5N         N577       A
2T         225        A
PE         020        A
```

Comment: an overly complicated solution for a fairly simple problem :(

Comment: @M.Ali OP needs only left... well, yes, complicated.